# Which preposition should you use: "concerns about/with something"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is the more correct preposition *about* vs. *with* in the following sentence?

- What concerns do you have *about* adopting?
- What concerns do you have *with* adopting?

[Here is a link to a poll if you wouldn't mind voting](http://www.easypolls.net/poll.html?p=582bb21ce4b0d643a29a5e12).

Comment: I've just voted for 'about' in the poll only to find myself in the minority. I would say 'What do you see as the difficulties _with_ adopting' but not 'What concerns do you have _with_ adopting'. I wonder whether 'concerns ... with' is more common in the US and concerns...about' more common in the UK. There is also the form 'concerns...regarding' which is certainly used in the UK; I don't know whether it's used in the US or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would update this with the result of the poll that the original poster ran, so that future visitors to this site can see them no matter what happens to the linked site:

[image: Which of the following questions "reads" better? 65% answered "What concerns do you have about adopting?"; 35% answered "What concerns do you have with adopting?"; total votes: 17]

The following comment by BoldBen may also be valuable; it had one upvote at the time this answer post was made:

> I've just voted for 'about' in the poll only to find myself in the minority. I would say 'What do you see as the difficulties *with* adopting' but not 'What concerns do you have *with* adopting'. I wonder whether 'concerns ... with' is more common in the US and concerns...about' more common in the UK. There is also the form 'concerns...regarding' which is certainly used in the UK; I don't know whether it's used in the US or not. 
>   – [BoldBen](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191850/boldben) Nov 16 '16 at 9:25